# Why is overflow:hidden not working in chrome when parent div has a column-count

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The output should be:

[image]

but on chrome I'm getting this:

[image]

Removing the column-count property from div1 fixes it. Interestingly if you inspect and disable that property then re-enable it, everything’s fine. Is this a bug in Chrome?

```css
#div1 {
  column-count: 1;
}

#div2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

#div3 {
  transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=photo"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also reported this as a bug in chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=981279

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer as to why it's not working, but if you need a nasty-asse workaround in the meantime, this works for me:

```css
#div1 {
  column-count: 1;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#div2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

#div3 {
  transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
    <div id="div3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=photo"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As an answer to your question about if this is a bug: yes, it appears this is a long-lasting bug on Chromium  (original post back in 2011, and as you now found, the issue is still there)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=84030

Comment: this is a different bug

Comment: @jeremy Lucas, That big describes content that is hidden but should be visible. Mine is the opposite.